# How to make a cache solution for a shared resource in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am new to caching and also to the problem that I have in hand. The conventional caching that I understand works in a way that a resource is cached when it is retrieved and then the cache is used later on. On creation, updation and deletion, the cache is deleted to be made a new one the next time.

In the case of a resource that is owned by users, the user id also included in the cache key somehow so that it does not clash with the cache of other users.

Now, my problem is somewhat unique. I have a resource that is shared ie some of it owned by individual users but some of it is owned by all.

So now, when creation, updation and deletion happens, I have to delete cache for all users because it might affected all their result sets since some of the items were shared. And then the cache for all users will have to recalculated at the next retrieval by that particular user which makes this pretty inefficient.

Has someone encountered a similar problem and can tell me how to go around this?

Comment: Did you look into the tagging system of Laravel's cache? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache#cache-tags

Comment: I did now. But how can this help? Can you give me an idea? Any help is appreciated. Thanks anyway.